# How does the getClass() is implemented in java?

Tags: java

I have a code like this :

```
public class QueueSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new QueueSample().getClass());
    }

}
```

it prints:

```
class QueueSample
```

`getClass()` method is coming from the `Object` class. Looking at the source code of `Object`, I can see only method definition like this:

```
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

If its not implemented here, where and how does this method got implemented?

Comment: `getClass()` is a native method call.. So, you will not have the source code of that method in the source code shipped with JDK.

Comment: @TheLostMind: So, then how does the native code does implement it?

Comment: @batman Why do you want to know? This is something very complicated that completely depends on the way the Java Virtual Machine is implemented and how it's internal data structures function. It can differ per vendor and version of the JVM. As long as getClass() works like the specification describes it, you don't need to know how it's implemented.

Comment: @batman - You can get the source code [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It is never wrong to get some insight into how stuff works internally, and be it for learning purposes only.

Comment: @Andreas As I said, it requires you to know the entire JVM (and the OP would need to specify which vendor and version) If that's the OP's question, then it's certainly "too broad" for SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @TheLostMind mentions, you can get the source code from OpenJDK - looking into a somewhat [newer version (JDK9)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/c8efbf0a974b/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Object.c), the `getClass()` native method is implemented like

```
JNIEXPORT jclass JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_getClass(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{
    if (this == NULL) {
        JNU_ThrowNullPointerException(env, NULL);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, this);
    }
}
```

So, essentially what it does is it delegates to the JVM's environment and uses the `GetObjectClass()` function to return the `Class` object. You can use this as a starting point - if you want to go deeper, I suggest that you check out the JDK source code from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ using mercurial, so that you can browse through it.

As @Holger mentions, there are some performance optimizations when using a JIT compiler such as hotspot - for example, [Performance techniques used in the Hotspot JVM](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques#PerformanceTechniques-Intrinsics) says "`Object.getClass()` is one or two instructions.". What this means is that the above code shows one possible implementation of `Object.getClass()`, but this implementation might change during runtime and/or based on the actual JVM (interpreted/JITted, client/server, Oracle standard/JRockit, ...)

Comment: This is the “ordinary code” that might be invoked in interpreted mode. It is very likely that hotspot optimizers know the `getClass()` method and replace it with something else when it appears in a hotspot, using the surrounding context of the invocation to predict the result and looking at what you are actually doing with the result. See https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques#PerformanceTechniques-Intrinsics